# Mostrar e resetar <select> com o checkbox em jquery

Tags: jquery

No código de exemplo em anexo, valor do item é multiplicado pelo value do respectivo select e exibe o subtotal e total.

Minha dúvida (de iniciante), é como ocultar e remover da conta o selectlist quando o respectivo checkbox estiver desmarcado, ou seja, ao marcar o checkbox, aparece o respectivo selectlist iniciando sempre no primeiro item da lista(1 unidade).

Até consegui fazer funcionar sem Jquery porem ficou igual um "frankenstein"
Desde já obrigado, a todos que puderem ajudar.

Segue o exemplo incompleto, com jquery:
https://jsfiddle.net/hLapmkq9/

Comment: Você quer que somente some quando o checkbox estiver selecionado, ou somente quando o usuário selecionar um item do selectlist.

Comment: Porque não trava seu select até que o checkbox seja selecionado?

Comment: Ao selecionar o primeiro checkbox, mostra o primeiro selectlist e adiciona-lo na conta

Comment: Acho que ficou meio confuso e editei a pergunta original @marlon

Comment: @DaniloFagundes olha se isto que você precisa: https://jsfiddle.net/mtsys/hLapmkq9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que precisas é de encontrar uma lógica para saber qual o input e select que funcionam juntos. Neste caso parece-me que o elemento comum é a `tr`, ou seja ambos partilham a mesma linha.

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('table input:checked').each(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var qty = tr.find('.qty').val();
    var price = $(this).val();
    var amount = (qty * price) || 0;
    sum += amount;
    tr.find('.amount').text(amount);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/

Repara que uso como ponto de partida somente os inputs selecionados com `$('table input:checked')`. Por isso o `this` dentro da função será o input.

Comment: Boa tarde @sergio. Quase lá: 
Com sua dica cheguei a esse ponto, falta só fazer o reset do selectlist funcionar:

https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/1/

Comment: Cometi algum erro na linha 8 do JS ?

Comment: @DaniloFagundes ah, querias esconder o select também? ok,  nesse caso seria melhor assim: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/2/ <- é isso que procuras?

Comment: seguindo a logica do seu ultimo código, como "resetar" o selectlist sempre para a primeiro valor, quando desmarcar o respectivo checkbox? Ex: "('selectedIndex',0)"

Comment: Consegui o resultado e o reset do selectlist utilizando o código anterior: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/3/ . Obrigado pela ajuda. ;)

Comment: @DaniloFagundes nesse caso basta `if (!this.checked) select.prop('selectedIndex', 0);` assim: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/8/